# how to make 1 by n dataframe from series in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a huge dataframe, and I index it like so:

`df.ix[<integer>]`

Depending on the index, sometimes this will have only one row of values.  Pandas automatically converts this to a Series, which, quite frankly, is annoying because I can't operate on it the same way I can a df.

How do I either:

1)  Stop pandas from converting and keep it as a dataframe ?

OR

2)  easily convert the resulting series back to a dataframe ?

`pd.DataFrame(df.ix[<integer>])` does not work because it doesn't keep the original columns.  It treats the `<integer>` as the column, and the columns as indices.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do `df.ix[[n]]` to get a one-row dataframe of row `n`.