# pandas: Select one-row data frame instead of series

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a pandas `DataFrame` with a bunch of different data types, and I want to select a single row.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : 1.,
                     'B' : pd.Timestamp('20130102'),
                     'C' : pd.Series(1,index=list(range(4)),dtype='float32'),
                     'D' : np.array([3] * 4,dtype='int32'),
                     'E' : pd.Categorical(["test","train","test","train"]),
                     'F' : 'foo' })

row = df2.loc[0]
```

`row` is a `Series` object. Since `Series` only contains one type of data, the `dtype` is the most general one, `object`.

```
>>> row 
A                      1
B    2013-01-02 00:00:00
C                      1
D                      3
E                   test
F                    foo
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

I can convert this `Series` into a one-row `DataFrame`, but because the `Series` has `dtype == object`, so does each row in the converted `DataFrame`:

```
>>> row_as_df = row.to_frame().T
>>> row_as_df.dtypes
A    object
B    object
C    object
D    object
E    object
F    object
dtype: object
```

What I want instead is for it to have the same `dtypes` as `df2`:

```
>>> df2.dtypes
A           float64
B    datetime64[ns]
C           float32
D             int32
E          category
F            object
dtype: object
```

Is there a way to select the row from the data frame and have it give me a one-row data frame, with all the original data types, instead of a series?

Comment: There is a solution in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458865/how-to-make-1-by-n-dataframe-from-series-in-pandas

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I needed. Not sure why that question didn't show up when I searched... oh well.

Comment: @Apocheir: (Tip) google searching `site: stackoverflow.com one row dataframe series` will restrict the search to pages in the `stackoverflow.com` domain.